# Different accuracy in model.fit() and predict_classes()

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, keras

Can Someone please explain why there are different accuracy in model.fit() and predict_classes() ?

model.evaluate gave ('Test score:', 0.5457103276905948) and ('Test accuracy:', 0.94977169167505548) using:

```
score = model.evaluate(x_val, y_val, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
# print ('Raw test score:', score)
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

and the accuracy_score of model.predict_classes on Train and test data gave 
Training accuracy:94.17% and 
Testing accuracy: 88.61%

Code is given here: https://gist.github.com/dirko/375397bc942d134a3c82d0dd514f3fea

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Have you run `model.metrics_names` to find out what your `score[0]` and `score[1]` represent?

Comment: @cardamom, yes, score[0] is loss and score[1] is accuracy.